# Why my page don't scrolling down when i touch several times a link with anchor?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a link with anchor that should return me to the top of my page. But when i touch this link several times my page don't scrolls down next 5 seconds. Why it happens?

HTML:

```
<div class="back">
    <a href="#top" class="back__link">Вверх</a>
</div>
```

CSS(if you need it):

```
.back
    position: fixed
    left: 90%
    top: 80%
    text-align: center
    padding-top: 25px
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
    width: 80px
    height: 55px
    background: $main-color
    border-radius: 50%
    z-index: 10
    &__link
        display: block
        height: 100%
        padding-top: 25px
        font-size: 20px
        color: #fff
        font-weight: bold
        text-decoration: underline
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".back").on("click","a", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
        top = $(id).offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
    $('.menu').css('transform', 'translateX(-100%)');
    $('.menu').css('transition', '0.7s');
});
```

});

Comment: I have removed this line and 'event' from function's argument but problem still exists

Comment: Unable to replicate, your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/1u5oktdb/. Note that I had to re-write the CSS, but that will not affect the JS behaviour in this case./

Comment: It's strange, but problem exists even on this website. But i have found solution. I have pasted this script instead of last

Comment: const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]')

for (let anchor of anchors) {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    const blockID = anchor.getAttribute('href').substr(1)
    
    document.getElementById(blockID).scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'start'
    })
  })
}